# How do I make the x-axis ticks sufficiently separated

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

I'm doing exploratory analysis on Nifty stock data of last 12 months. When I do a boxplot of High and Low Prices, the x-axis ticks are too much in quantity and are getting all over each other (unable to read).
How do I make it so that the ticks are sufficiently separated and visible to read?
Image of the plot attached along with the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZWYs.png)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
sns.boxplot(x=data['High'], y=data['Low'])
plt.title('High vs Low Prices')
plt.xlabel('High Price')
plt.ylabel('Low Price')
plt.show()
```